# how to remove div tag with id=selection_bubble in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a web page in asp.net
I see this web page in my browser. When I go to "inspect element" in my chrome browser, I see a `div` tag with `id=selection_bubble` before end `body` tag.
What is this and How to be created this and How do I remove this?

Comment: I have never heard it, have sou serached your project for `selection_bubble`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, I don't find any things!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also just came across a `div` with `id="dic_bubble"` and `class="selection_bubble"` in chrome as a child of the `body` tag. Like you, I searched my project files and found nothing. Neither did any other browser have the `div`.

It is related to a chrome extension and thus should not affect your site for users.

To remove the `div` for yourself, disable the chrome "Dictionary.com Extension."

Comment: Very Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of some extensions installed on your chrome. If you wanna check if it is because of extensions just open an incognito(private) tab in chrome and enter your page again. The difference is that extensions are disabled in incognito tab. When I had this problem I opened my page in incognito tab and the problem was gone. So be sure that it is because of extensions and users won't face this problem.
(to open an incognito tab click on the three dots to the top right of chrome and then click on the "New incognito tab")
I wish i could help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check "Entire solution" when searching and that you're searching in all filetypes. Also try doing a search for selection and another for bubble in case it's concatenated somewhere.